# Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back. FastApi

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, rollback

I have Fast-api code base. I am getting error

> Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/8s2b)

I have figured it out that I am having

```
psycopg2.errors.IdleInTransactionSessionTimeout
```

terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction before the rollback error. The rollback error keeps coming continuously until I restart or rebuild my project.

My codebase is:

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

from config import settings


engine = create_engine(settings.DATABASE_URL, connect_args={f"options": "-c timezone=" + settings.TIME_ZONE})
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(SessionLocal)
db = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
```

A service where i execute database transactions -

query_utils.py

```
from database import db

class QueryBuilder:
   ...... some functions to build the query ......

   def bulk_upsert_execute(self):

      db.get_bind().execute(text(self.query_string))
      db.commit()
      db.close()
```

Another model where i use the db instance -

object_save_and_get_model.py

```
from database import db

class MainObjectGetModel(BaseModel):
    object_name: str

    @validator('object_name')
    def validate_object_existence(cls, v) -> SavedObject:
        result = db.query(SavedObject).filter(SavedObject.name == v).first()

        if not result:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="File not found.")

        return result
```

i have tried using -
database.py-

```
def handle_session_rollback(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        session = Session()

        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            session.commit()
            return result

        except Exception as e:
            session.rollback()
            raise

        finally:
            session.close()

    return wrapper
```

query_utils.py -

```
from database import db, handle_session_rollback
class QueryBuilder:
   ...... some functions to build the query ......

   @handle_session_rollback
   def bulk_upsert_execute(self):

       db.get_bind().execute(text(self.query_string))
       db.commit()
       db.close()
```

it actually do rollback if any exception occurs. i have checked, but for **IdleInTransactionSessionTimeout** it actually don't works.

I couldn't figured it out why the **IdleInTransactionSessionTimeout** occurs. I have also tried -

```
try:
    # Perform your operations within the session
    # ...

    # Commit the transaction
    db.commit()

except Exception as e:
    # Roll back the transaction in case of an exception
    db.rollback()

    # Handle the exception as needed
    # ...

finally:
    # Close the session
    db.close()
```

gives the same result as handle_session_rollback. How can i handle the  rollback in this scenario...?

**[note: I am using PostgreSQL]**

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have started a transaction and not run a query for so long a timeout has been triggered. This is configured in your PostgreSQL server.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT

You won't see this until you interact with the server in some way - typically by running a query.

Solution: don't open a transaction and "sit on it", open it with the first statement you want in that transaction.